Is it possible to call an instance variable in a static method in flutter?
I am using background_downloader plugin in flutter. So I created a static method for my callback function. But I wish to be able to store the values from the callback in my getx variable.
How can I do that?
Download Manager class
final DownloadController downloadController = Get.find(); 

static setup(){
    FileDownloader().registerCallbacks(
      taskStatusCallback: taskStatusCallback,
      taskProgressCallback: taskProgressCallback,
    );
}

void taskStatusCallback(TaskStatusUpdate update){
   downloadController.backgroundTaskStatus.value = update.status;
}

But I get error
Instance members can't be accessed from a static method. Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method.

You can access instance variables in a static method, but you need an instance (i.e., an object) to retrieve them from.  How would you expect it to work otherwise?  In your case, perhaps you want var instance = FileDownloader(); instance.registerCallbacks(taskStatusCallback: instance.taskStatusCallback, ...);?

@jamesdlin you mean I can make that reference but I have to called create instance in the static setup function? Pardon my questions, i am still a beginner

I don't understand exactly what you're asking.  You need to construct an object instance and then access the instance members on that instance.

I tried that. it works for me
